# Rounded Color Picker in AngularJS - Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm in a project which I have to allow the user to pick a color as its prefer. Searching for Color Picker plugins I only found color pickers squared or with seekbars to adjust R, G, and B values to get a color. I'm searching for something like this:

[image]

Does someone know a way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give this Farbatastic Color Picker a try, it's jQuery so could work with Ionic and Angular: http://acko.net/blog/farbtastic-jquery-color-picker-plug-in/

Comment: Could work with jQuery ? Doesn't it need jQuery lib ?

Comment: Thanks @mJunaidSalaat